# How to listen to all events in Internet Explorer and send them to another process

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, web

I'd like to listen to all the events that the dom\html fires and I'd like to send them to another process to be processed (or to an app server - second best option)

I may have to handle issues like SSL site.

What are my choices ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options that I found (and I'd appreciate some more)
1. Inject javascript that handles all events and send the data using ajax maybe with CORS
2. listen to windows events and connect to the IE process in order to get the dom.